# Best practices using JPA to load object from query with a list member

Tags: jpa, jpql, pojo

I'm getting started with JPA and I want to know the best way to achieve something like this:
I need to implement a service that returns a list of scripts, and each script has a list of parameters. I simplified the query, but it is something like this:

```
(SELECT 
    p.DESC 
FROM 
    INPUT_PARAMETERS p
    INNER JOIN SCRIPT_PARAMS sp ON p.PARAM_ID = sc.PARAM_I
    INNER JOIN SCRIPT s ON s.SCRIPT_ID = sc.SCRIPT_ID
WHERE
    s.NAME = 'name')
UNION
(SELECT 
    p.DESC 
FROM 
    OUPUT_PARAMETERS p
    INNER JOIN SCRIPT_PARAMS sp ON p.PARAM_ID = sc.PARAM_I
    INNER JOIN SCRIPT s ON s.SCRIPT_ID = sc.SCRIPT_ID
WHERE
    s.NAME = 'name')
```

And I want to return a list of POJO objects that are something like:

```
public class Script {
    private String name;
    private List<String> params;
    public Script(){}
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String pName)
    {
        name = pName;
    }
    public List<String> getParams()
    {
        return params;
    }
    public void setParams(List<String> pParams)
    {
        params = pParams;
    }   
}
```

I want to know what is the best way to load the POJO object from a query. Is it best to build a JPQL query, or can I use a Native Named Query, and do I need to get a object[] and construct my POJOs manually, or can I use JPA to load the objects from the query?

Answer (score 0):

**You can only construct instances of Script manually**. When querying with JPQL, reason is that [constructor expression](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/apirefs.1111/e13946/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_constructor) cannot take List as argument. Additionally JPQL does not have unions.

Also with SQL query you cannot construct Script directly, because result can be only scalars or entity.